# gdb -x shared library breakpoint

Tags: linux, bash, gdb, breakpoints

I have a list of breakpoints which I want to add each time I debug a particular program. I created a file that contain the breakpoints and used gdb -x "file" commend, but all the breakpoints that are pending on future shared library load wasn't added. Is there a way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your script set breakpoints in shared libraries as pending and when the shared libraries are loaded your breakpoints will be correctly set.

```
(gdb) help set breakpoint pending
Set debugger's behavior regarding pending breakpoints.
If on, an unrecognized breakpoint location will cause gdb to create a
pending breakpoint.  If off, an unrecognized breakpoint location results in
an error.  If auto, an unrecognized breakpoint location results in a
user-query to see if a pending breakpoint should be created.
```

And this is an example of a script (suppose `print_in_lib` in in a shared library that will be loaded with `dlopen`):

```
file main
set breakpoint pending on
b print_in_lib
r
```

And this is its output:

```
host: srv2-x64rh5-01, OS: Linux 2.6.18-238.el5>gdb -q
Function "print_in_lib" not defined.
Breakpoint 1 (print_in_lib) pending.
warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x2aaaaaaab000
thousands: 1
print_debug: 0

Breakpoint 1, print_in_lib (print_debug=0) at my_lib.cpp:7
7           if (print_debug) {
(gdb) bt
#0  print_in_lib (print_debug=0) at my_lib.cpp:7
#1  0x00000000004008ab in main (argc=<value optimized out>, argv=<value optimized out>) at main.cpp:37
(gdb)
```