# monitor linux dynamic library

Tags: gdb, dynamic-linking, ldd, ltrace, gdbinit

I would like to monitor(debug) a linux dynamic library written in C.
I want to see when and what parameters are passed to it.

The library to monitor 'X', is invoked by another dynamic library 'Y'.
Both 'X and 'Y' appear in /proc/pid/maps of the executable 'A'.

Using ltrace, on the executable did not show lib X or Y.
The executable is using multiple threads.

Also, when using ldd command on the exec it doesn't mention anything about libs X or Y.
ldd Y, shows that Y needs X.

Using ldd on all the libs, execs in the project doesn't mention anyone who would need Y.
Yet Y appears to be loaded in the /proc/pid/maps of the exec.

I'm not sure what steps I could take in order to debug the X lib, any advice is appreciated.

Comment: `Y` might be loaded at runtime via `dlopen`.

Comment: `strace` should detect the library file load.

Comment: @KerrekSB I see that the ltrace documentation states `Calls to dlopen()ed libraries will not be traced.`

Comment: `strace` is not the same as `ltrace`. You could also use `gdb` and put breakpoints on appropriate function names of the indirectly loaded library *X*

Comment: Does `LD_PRELOAD` trick work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If user756235 can run it under gdb then this is an approach using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11273702/184968) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10748611/184968). The only question is to make a full list of functions in a shared library X: `nm ./libX.so | grep "T "`

And then create .gdbinit (in my case I control args of `print_in_lib`):

```
host: srv2-x64rh5-01, OS: Linux 2.6.18-238.el5>more .gdbinit
file main
set pagination off
set logging file gdb.txt
set breakpoint pending on
set logging on
b print_in_lib
commands
info args
continue
end
r
set logging off
quit
```

And when I run `gdb`:

> host: srv2-x64rh5-01, OS: Linux 2.6.18-238.el5>gdb -q Function
>   "print_in_lib" not defined. Breakpoint 1 (print_in_lib) pending.
>   warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file
>   system-supplied DSO at 0x2aaaaaaab000 thousands: 1 print_debug: 0
>
> Breakpoint 1, print_in_lib (print_debug=0, index=0) at my_lib.cpp:7 7 
>   if (print_debug) { print_debug = 0 index = 0
>
> Breakpoint 1, print_in_lib (print_debug=0, index=1) at my_lib.cpp:7 7 
>   if (print_debug) { print_debug = 0 index = 1
>
> Breakpoint 1, print_in_lib (print_debug=0, index=2) at my_lib.cpp:7 7 
>   if (print_debug) { print_debug = 0 index = 2
>
> Breakpoint 1, print_in_lib (print_debug=0, index=3) at my_lib.cpp:7 7 
>   if (print_debug) { print_debug = 0 index = 3